# copy new created folder in directory using batch file

Tags: batch-file, copy, directory

Suppose source folder is `C:\Users\abc\Desktop\test`. I want to copy a newly created folder in  this directory. I do not know the name of newly created folder, but once copied that folder, I want to have the name of that folder to use it further.

How to solve this problem using batch file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test this:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\test" /b /od /ad') do set "lastest_folder=%%~fa"
echo "%lastest_folder%"
pause
```